# Why does the use of "cmd" in .bat resolve correctly?

Tags: command-line, batch-file

While searching for the correct method to run a .bat script and have the `cmd` window remain active on completion, I learned one of two popular methods is to include `cmd /k file.bat` in the script, where "file.bat" refers to itself.

While I understand the functional result of the above, what I can't seem to wrap my mind around is how — conceptually — it executes and resolves correctly?

From my own uneducated inference, I think it has something to do with the `/k` argument, whose function is explained as:

> Carries out the command specified by string but remains

Still, even if it enables the script to prevent looping itself, how does it not break its own execution?

Apologies if this is super obvious or if I'm misunderstanding something fundamental, I've no formal education or training on the topic.

**EDIT:**

Well, that was silly of me!  I saw in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957076/keep-cmd-open-after-bat-file-executes) that the syntax was arranged the way I indicated above...which *does* loop the script, so I should have actually tested for myself first before blindly believing without proper context (and I'm always saying "trust but verify", too, what a hypocrite ).

I'd like to confirm then, since I misunderstood the usage to begin with, would the *correct* usage be, e.g., ...?

```
@Echo=off
WMIC useraccount get name,sid
cmd /k
```

In terms of what I wanted to practically apply this knowledge to, I simply want to be able to run the .bat from file explorer or shell:startup, and have the `cmd` prompt stay open for further use (which `pause` does not achieve).

PS: If I'm to be nit-picky, any way to achieve the above *without* echoing the `cmd /k` back?

Comment: The last line of the script is read, executed and instead of quitting cmd it doesn't? What's the actual confusion?

Comment: @Seth I didn't realize ```cmd /k``` needed to go last, in the post that I have reference above, the answer selected had shown a different usage.

Comment: Your idea about using the `/k` switch is kind of odd.You could use a link instead to have it the proper way around (run the batch with `/k`). `cmd /K C:\temp\a.bat` and `cmd /C C:\temp\a.bat` should make it easy to see the difference. Just but you `wmic` command in that bat and try to run it directly like that using your cmd.

Comment: If you double-click a batch-file it's actually run by `cmd /C "D:\path\to\your\file.bat" %*`; do you want to change this to `cmd /K ...`, so the `cmd` window remains open after the batch-file quits?

Comment: @aschipfl Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear on that, I'd like for the ```cmd``` window to stay open and return to it's default state.  Adding ```cmd /K``` as a separate line seems to accomplish this, although it literally echos back ```cmd /K```.  While it isn't a big deal, I'm using this in a scenario where I want everything on screen to be human readable, and don't want to have to explain to users questioning what that line means.

Comment: Just adding `cmd /K` (or `@cmd /K` to avoid the echo) opens another `cmd` instance, so the environment changes (variables, current directories) of the script become lost...

Answer (score 2):

As far as why `cmd` resolves, there are a couple of good explanations over on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366381/cmd-works-but-c-windows-system32-cmd-exe-does-not) - essentially `cmd` is interpreted as `%ComSpec%`, which is your system's environment variable for the cmd.exe's full location (usually `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`).

As far as the context of your question - if you have `cmd /k yourbatfile.bat` inside yourbatfile.bat, it's just going to loop. If you're wanting your window to stay open for troubleshooting reasons I highly recommend just throwing a `pause` at the end of it/after whatever section(s) you're having issues with.

The wording for `/k` is [a little different here](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) since it says it "returns to the command prompt" - essentially, adding `/k` is like opening cmd.exe and using it, while having no `/k` is like executing a command from a Run window.

You can test this by opening Run and executing `ipconfig /all` - your window will close immediately after `ipconfig` finishes; but if you open Run and execute `cmd /k ipconfig /all` - your window will return you to a command prompt.